# React ant design reset only one input filed

Tags: reactjs, antd, react-typescript

Im using my project for React ant design 4 . I have some conflict on the form . I want to know how to reset only one (Note) field any one know the solution

Thanks

**[stazkblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-nazmet-ldugao?file=index.js)**

code here

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import './index.css';
import { Form, Input, Button, Select } from 'antd';
const { Option } = Select;
const layout = {
  labelCol: {
    span: 8,
  },
  wrapperCol: {
    span: 16,
  },
};
const tailLayout = {
  wrapperCol: {
    offset: 8,
    span: 16,
  },
};

const Demo = () => {
  const [form] = Form.useForm();

  const onGenderChange = (value) => {
    switch (value) {
      case 'male':
        form.setFieldsValue({
          note: 'Hi, man!',
        });
        return;

      case 'female':
        form.setFieldsValue({
          note: 'Hi, lady!',
        });
        return;

      case 'other':
        form.setFieldsValue({
          note: 'Hi there!',
        });
        return;
    }
  };

  const onFinish = (values) => {
    console.log(values);
  };

  const onReset = () => {
    form.resetFields();
  };

  const onFill = () => {
    form.setFieldsValue({
      note: 'Hello world!',
      gender: 'male',
    });
  };

  return (
    <Form {...layout} form={form} name="control-hooks" onFinish={onFinish}>
      <Form.Item
        name="note"
        label="Note"
        rules={[
          {
            required: true,
          },
        ]}
      >
        <Input />
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item
        name="gender"
        label="Gender"
        rules={[
          {
            required: true,
          },
        ]}
      >
        <Select
          placeholder="Select a option and change input text above"
          onChange={onGenderChange}
          allowClear
        >
          <Option value="male">male</Option>
          <Option value="female">female</Option>
          <Option value="other">other</Option>
        </Select>
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item
        noStyle
        shouldUpdate={(prevValues, currentValues) => prevValues.gender !== currentValues.gender}
      >
        {({ getFieldValue }) => {
          return getFieldValue('gender') === 'other' ? (
            <Form.Item
              name="customizeGender"
              label="Customize Gender"
              rules={[
                {
                  required: true,
                },
              ]}
            >
              <Input />
            </Form.Item>
          ) : null;
        }}
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item {...tailLayout}>
        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
          Submit
        </Button>
        <Button htmlType="button" onClick={onReset}>
          Reset
        </Button>
        <Button type="link" htmlType="button" onClick={onFill}>
          Fill form
        </Button>
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Demo />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add an array of namePath in your `form.resetFields` call

```
const onReset = () => {
   form.resetFields(["note"]);
};
```

Just tested it with your code and it works : https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-nazmet-jh2cc1?file=index.js

More info : https://ant.design/components/form/#FormInstance